# Add title to Networkx plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I want my code to create a plot with a title. With the code below the plot gets created but no title. Can someone clue me in on what I am doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd   
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import community
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

...

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist((df), 'AXIS1', 'AXIS2');
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True) 
plt.title('TITLE')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('test.png');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can only think of some intermediate step triggering a call to `plt.show` before your call to `plt.title` (though it doesn't look like that should be the case with the shared code). Try setting the title beforehand, and setting an `ax`, here's an example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title('Random graph')
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10,0.2)
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True, node_color='lightgreen', ax=ax)
_ = ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Probably OP doesn't need this anymore, but for future searchers: the title shows if it's added before the call to `nx.draw()`, e.g.

```
plt.figure()  
plt.title(plot_title)
nx.draw(G, node_size=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that define a new graph with one node:

```
title=nx.Graph()
title.add_node(f'Title')
nx.draw(title, with_labels = True,  pos=nx.spring_layout(title, seed=0, center=(0, 0)), node_color='#fff')
```

Then show this graph alongside your desired graph, you should play with the center parameter to put this node in an appropriate location. This is how I added labels R(2), R(1), ... in the following graph.

[image: This is how I added labels R(2), R(1) , ...]