# NetworkX Plot Titles - Interactive Plots

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I've been following a [tutorial](https://www.algorhythmblog.be/2022/04/05/visualizing-multicollinearity-in-python/) for visualising multicollinearity and have been building an interactive network graph. I would like to add a title to the plot and I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038379/add-title-to-networkx-plot) which I thought would help, however it is not about an interactive plot and when I try the answers, I end up with my same interactive graph with no title, and then a small empty non interactive plot below with a title.

My code currently looks like:

```
plt.title('Network Graph Showing Correlated Metabolites at Adjustable Correlation Thresholds')
threshold_choice = widgets.FloatSlider(description="Threshold", value=0.8, min=0.1, max=1, step=0.05, 
                                    continuous_update=False, orientation='horizontal', layout=Layout(width='500px'), 
                                    style=dict(description_width= 'initial'))

network = go.FigureWidget(data=[go.Scatter(x=[], y=[], mode='lines', text=[],  line=dict(color='#cc78bc', width=2.5), 
                                    marker=dict(size=16, line_width=5,line=dict(color='#cc78bc',width=2))),
                                    go.Scatter(x=[], y=[],mode='markers+text', textposition="top center", text=[], 
                                    hoverinfo='text',textfont_size=12, marker=dict(size=10, color=[],line_width=1))],
                                    layout=go.Layout( showlegend=False, annotations=[], margin=dict(t=40, b=0, l=0, r=0), 
                                    width=950, height=800))
df = AlzZ.copy()
correlation_matrix = cor.to_numpy()

def plot_corr_graph(change):
    threshold, corr_mode = None, None
    threshold = change.new
    
    tr_ind = np.triu_indices(correlation_matrix.shape[0])
    correlation_matrix[tr_ind] = 0
    G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(correlation_matrix)
    G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, lambda x: df.columns.tolist()[x])
   
    remove = []
    
    for col1, col2, weight in G.edges(data=True):
      if math.isnan(weight["weight"]):
        remove.append((col1,col2))
    
      if abs(weight["weight"]) < threshold:
        remove.append((col1,col2))
    
    G.remove_edges_from(remove)
    
    remove = []
    edges = list(sum(G.edges, ()))
    
    for node in G.nodes:
      if node not in edges:
        remove.append(node)
    G.remove_nodes_from(remove)
    mst = nx.maximum_spanning_tree(G)
    
    def assign_color(col):
      return colorlistMCLN

    def assign_color_edge(correlation):
      if correlation < 0:
        return "#BF0603"
      else:
        return "#00CC66"
    edge_colors = []
    node_colors = []
    for key, value in nx.get_edge_attributes(mst, 'weight').items():
        edge_colors.append(assign_color_edge(value))
    for key, value in dict(mst.degree).items():
        node_colors.append(assign_color(key))
      
    labels = {n:n for n in mst.nodes()}
    node_x = []
    node_y = []
    
    tree = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(mst, k=0.25).items()
    
    for node, (x_,y_) in tree:
        node_x.append(x_)
        node_y.append(y_)
        
    def get_dim_of_node(name):
        for node, (x,y) in tree:
            if node == name:
                return x,y
        
    edge_x = []
    edge_y = []
    
    weights= []
    for node1, node2, w in mst.edges(data=True):
        x0, y0 = get_dim_of_node(node1)
        x1, y1 =  get_dim_of_node(node2)
        edge_x.append(x0)
        edge_x.append(x1)
        edge_x.append(None)
        edge_y.append(y0)
        edge_y.append(y1)
        edge_y.append(None)
        weights.append((round(w["weight"],1), (x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2))
                              
    with network.batch_update():
        network.data[1].x = node_x
        network.data[1].y = node_y
        network.data[1].text = list(labels)
        network.data[1].marker.color = node_colors
                          
        network.data[0].x = edge_x
        network.data[0].y = edge_y
        network.data[0].text = list(weights)
        network.update_layout(xaxis_zeroline=False, yaxis_zeroline=False, xaxis_showgrid=False, yaxis_showgrid=False, 
                              plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')

threshold_choice.observe(plot_corr_graph, names="value")
widgets.VBox([threshold_choice, network])
```

With my output looking like:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX9br.png)

I've also tried putting

```
plt.title('title')
```

between the threshold_choice object and the network object, and have tried

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title('title')
```

below the correlation_matrix object - which has the same result.

When I place it within the function, below the threshold object it which did not produce any plots with titles, just the original network graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out:

The issue is the interactive graph is not actually a plot at all from the perspective of the code. It is a **FigureWidget**. Knowing this makes it much easier to find the right documentation.

Initially I had been looking here: [NetworkX Documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html)

However you actually need to be looking at [this page](https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget/) in the plotly documentation.

In the example above (in the question) it means changing the network object to this:

```
network = go.FigureWidget(data=[go.Scatter(x=[], y=[], mode='lines', text=[],  line=dict(color='#cc78bc', width=2.5), 
                                    marker=dict(size=16, line_width=5,line=dict(color='#cc78bc',width=2))),
                                    go.Scatter(x=[], y=[],mode='markers+text', textposition="top center", text=[], 
                                    hoverinfo='text',textfont_size=12, marker=dict(size=10, color=[],line_width=1))],
                                    layout=go.Layout(showlegend=False, annotations=[], margin=dict(t=40, b=0, l=0, r=0), 
                                    width=950, height=800, title='Network Graph Showing Correlated Metabolites at Adjustable Correlation Thresholds'))
```

The title gets included in the layout argument as `title='your title'`